# Vue3 property 'x' does not exist on type 'Function' for global property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

I have a Quasar app and seem to be having a weird issue.
I am trying to define a global variable that is an object just containing meta info about the app.
The app compiles fully, and the correct info shows up in the HTML, but I get an error in VSCode.

src/boot/BackChat.js

```
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers';

const version = '0.0.0';

const backChat = {
  version
};


export default boot(({ app, router, store }) => {
  app.config.globalProperties.backChat = backChat;
});
```

Login.vue

```
// ...
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      backChat: this.backChat
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

[image: Error in Login.vue on backChat.version]

Am I using this interface wrong or is this just a bug with the Vue file validation? It seems it thinks "backChat" in Login.vue is a function. If I change the data() to mounted(), it is no longer a function, but then I cannot access it in the DOM. I am very new to Vue.

Comment: May be just a problem with type inference - in Vue 3 (which you seem using) you should define your components with [defineComponent](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#definecomponent)

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround which is the simplest approach. I am not sure if this is how your *supposed* to do it but, since it was thinking that it was a function, I just made the globalProperty a function that returns the object.

src/boot/BackChat.js

```
// ...
export default boot(({ app, router, store }) => {
  app.config.globalProperties.$backChat = () => backChat;
});
```

Login.vue

```
// ...
data() {
    return {
      username,
      password,
      backChat: this.$backChat()
    };
},
```

This fixes the error highlighted in the Vue file, and allows the same usage of the global object.